# Simplify arbitrary union expression in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_k$ be the the set  $A_k=\left\{x\in\left.\mathbb{R}\right|x^2-\left(4k+1\right)x+4k^2+2k<0\right\}$

I need to find a simplified way to rewrite the following group : $\mathbb{R}\setminus\left(\bigcup_{k\in z} A_k\right)$

By simplified I mean - **not using arbitrary union or arbitrary intersection**

The only equality I could think of is the following:$$\mathbb{R}\setminus\left(\bigcup_{k\in z} A_k\right) = \bigcup_{k\in z}\left[2k+1,2k+2\right]$$
But I still had to use arbitrary union, which I can't.

I would appriciate your assitance with finding the answer and prove the  equality.

Comment: How is $A_k$ a group?

Comment: It is a group with all x that solves $x2−(4k+1)x+4k2+2k<0$

Comment: I suspect you mean set rather than group which has a very specific meaning in mathematics.

Comment: yes I really ment to set and not a group.

Answer (score 1):

If you solve the inequality in $A_k$ you get $A_k = (2k,2k+1)$.

Then $\mathbb{R} \setminus \cup_k A_k = \cup_k[2k+1,2k+2]$.

You could write this as $[1,2]+2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think you have a mistake, I think that the correct answer is on my post, also I need to find a simplified way to write it (without using the arbitrary union sign.

Comment: @ShiranShaharabani: You are correct. What do you mean by arbitrary union? The union over $\mathbb{Z}$ is not exactly arbitrary?

Comment: I'm not sure I undersatan the answer [1,2]+2Z.

By arbitrary union I mean the following: 


${\displaystyle x\in \bigcup \mathbf {M} \iff \exists A\in \mathbf {M} ,\ x\in A.}$

Comment: What is **not** an arbitrary union? In general, if $A,B$ are two sets in, say,  a vector space, $A+B= \{a+b| a \-n A, b \in B\}$.